# Set JS variable name from another variable content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 arrays in JS (post_cycle_1, post_cycle_2 and post_cycle_3).

I have a variable, which name is `post_id`, and its value can be 1, 2 or 3.

I would like to get the first element of my array, which name is based on the post_id variable.

I don't know the correct syntax, like in php. `${"post_cycle_".$post_id."}[0]`

I've tried this way, but it didn't work.

```
alert("post_cycles_"+post_id[0])
```

Comment: Why are the arrays separate? It sounds like they belong together. Put then in an array, or object and look up the right one from there.

Comment: You really _don't_ want to be creating variables dynamically - see the comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables, for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate a dynamic variable name in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149233/concatenate-a-dynamic-variable-name-in-javascript)

Comment: It sounds like what you have is the wrong data structure.  What do these three arrays and ID value represent?